# Can a contract hold ERC1155 token?

Tags: solidity, erc-1155, staking

I am curious if ERC1155 token is able to stake or something else with smart contracts?

I know ERC721 is able but not sure about ERC1155.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that smart contracts supporting IERC1155Receiver can receive ERC1155 tokens.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc1155#IERC1155Receiver